# Erro no Android

Tags: android

Estou a criar um sistema de login no Android, mas por algum motivo está-me a dar este erro:

> Skipped 280 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

Alguém me pode ajudar?

```
package imm.pt.immsmart;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.graphics.Typeface;
    import android.os.StrictMode;
    import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
    import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
    import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
    import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
    import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
    import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
    import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
    import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
    import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {
        public void entrar(View view){

                    TextView user = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mail);
                    TextView pass = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.password);
                    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
                    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
                    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.66/immsmart/api.php");
                    try {
                        ArrayList<NameValuePair> valores = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                        valores.add(new BasicNameValuePair("task", "login"));
                        valores.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mail", user.getText().toString()));
                        valores.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass", pass.getText().toString()));
                        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(valores));
                        final HttpResponse resposta = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                        String res = EntityUtils.toString(resposta.getEntity());
                        if(res.equals("notfound")) {
                            user.setText("");
                            pass.setText("");
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
                            builder.setMessage("Dados Invalidos!");
                            builder.create();
                        }else{
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
                            builder.setMessage(res);
                            builder.create();
                            Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Login.this, Menu.class);
                            Login.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
                            Login.this.finish();
                        }
                    }catch (ClientProtocolException e){} catch (IOException e) {}
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como você está fazendo uma requesta na thread principal, ele prioriza isso à renderizar a tela, pulando frames, isso faz com que esse alerta apareça

Se recomenda não usar a thread principal para fazer requisições por esse e vários outros motivos.

Existem algumas boas bibliotecas que simplificam o controle de requisições com a Volley (hoje mantida pelo google https://github.com/google/volley) e o retrofit (https://github.com/square/retrofit)